# Tkinter grid system weird placement of buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create Hangman game in Tkinter. I am using buttons for choosing the letters, row for the grid is 0, and column is 0,1,2,3 up to 26. For down rows I have label, picture, etc. Now, there is space between first couple of buttons, and when picture is displayed, there is even more spaces, so they even can fit on the window. Here is example code and I will also attach picture from the original program. How can I fix the buttons? [picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgqFs.png)  [picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLZcQ.png)

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

window = Tk()

A = Button(text ="A").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
B = Button(text ="B").grid(row = 0, column = 1)
C = Button(text ="C").grid(row = 0, column = 2)
D = Button(text ="D").grid(row = 0, column = 3)
E = Button(text ="E").grid(row = 0, column = 4)

lbl = Label(text = "Hello").grid(row = 1, column = 0)

photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='hang1.jpg')

def show_image():
    pic = Label(window, image=photo).grid(row=3, column=2)

btn = Button(window, text = "Show image", command = show_image).grid(row = 2, column = 2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: you place other things on the same column but in a different row so obviously the column will expand to fit the larger item, you can use `columnspan` for those larger items such as the image to tell it to expand over multiple columns but I would suggest that you use `Frame`s to separate different parts of the game and don't do this: `var  = Widget(...).layout_method()` as  layout methods such as `.place`, `.grid` and `.pack` return `None` so assigning that to a variable is pointless

Comment: it is not `weird` but `standard` behavior. If you put bigger element in the same column then other elements in then same column will use more space - you have the same when you put bigger element in `Excel`. You could split it into two elments - top `Frame` and bottom `Frame` and every frame should use own grid. And you can put `Frame` with `pack()`

Answer (score 0):

It is not `weird` but `standard` behavior in all tools which use grid - ie. in `Excel` or in `<table>` in `HTML` .

If you put bigger element in the same column then other elements in then same column will use more space.

One method is to use `span` which inform then element/image should use more columns and then it will may not resize column - but if image will be too big then it may resize even all columns.

In `tkinter` in `grid()` you can use `column=0, columnspan=26` to use all columns for image. The same you can use for word and button and they will be centered.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferrred
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import string

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions at the beginning

def show_image():
    pic['image'] = photo
    
# --- main ---

span = len(string.ascii_uppercase)
print('span:', span)

window = tk.Tk()

for number, char in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase):
    b = tk.Button(window, text=char)  # use `window` as parent 
    b.grid(row=0, column=number)

lbl = tk.Label(window, text="Hello")
lbl.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=span)

pic = tk.Label(window)   # create empty label and later replace only image in this label
pic.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=span)

photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='lenna.png')

btn = tk.Button(window, text="Show image", command=show_image)
btn.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=24)

window.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

---

Other method is to use `Frame` to group buttons and then you can use different layout (`grid`, `pack`, `place`) to put other elements

In this version I use `frame` as parent for buttons.

I can also use different layout to put other elements - `pack()` - but I could use also `grid()` but it would be independent of the `grid` inside the `frame`.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferrred
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import string

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions at the beginning

def show_image():
    pic['image'] = photo
    
# --- main ---

span = len(string.ascii_uppercase)
print('span:', span)

window = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(window)
frame.pack()

for number, char in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase):
    b = tk.Button(frame, text=char)   # use `frame` as parent
    b.grid(row=0, column=number)

lbl = tk.Label(window, text="Hello")
lbl.pack()

pic = tk.Label(window)
pic.pack()

photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='lenna.png')

btn = tk.Button(window, text="Show image", command=show_image)
btn.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

---

**BTW:**

Image [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) from Wikipedia

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)